# How to paste Vim (normal mode) commands?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, repeated-commands

I need to copy a sequence of (normal mode) commands and then paste it to be executed in Vim.
When I try that now though it inserts it for me into the document.

How can I paste sequence of Vim (normal mode) commands?

This used to work; now with the auto-insert-mode I don't know how to make it
work again, or how to search for this in the documentation.

Using Vim in Terminal on macOS Monterey

#### Example

```
JJJj
```

(three joins and a cursor down one line)

Say I am in huge text file containing repetitive output which I want to
transform to make it visually more concise. I don't want to punch in those `JJJj`
every time. Pasting the commands repetitively a few dozen (or hundred)
times is faster, maybe even only for tens of times like
`JJJjJJJjJJJjJJJjJJJjJJJjJJJjJJJjJJJjJJJj`.

***BEFORE***

```
first line1
first line2
first line3
first line4
second line1
second line2
second line3
second line4
:
```

***AFTER***

```
first line1 first line2 first line3 first line4
second line1 second line2 second line3 second line4
:
```

This lets me transform thousands of lines within a few seconds.

Comment: You could try to disable bracketed-paste mode to make this work, but it’s probably easier to turn the commands into a short script you can execute.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the question correctly. In which form do you get the commands (an example would help)? Is it a list of commands each on its own like in a text document? They are separated with `|`? What do you try? Enter in command mode with `:` and paste `<C-r>+`?

Comment: Are the commands normal mode commands or command-line commands?

Comment: normal mode commands

Answer (score 2):

### How to run normal mode commands from your clipboard

If the normal mode commands are already in your `"+` clipboard register then you can run them as a macro by typing:

```
@+
```

If your clipboard isn't accessible from Vim (e.g. if Vim is compiled without clipboard support) then you can paste them into your document, yank them (e.g. with `y$` or `yiw`) and then run them from the yank register as a macro by typing:

```
@0
```

### How I'd actually solve your problem

Instead of writing your commands into your clipboard, I would record them as a macro and then run it a lot of times.

So for your example of running `JJJj` ten times, I would record a macro with:

```
qqJJJjq
```

And then run it 9 more times with:

```
9@q
```

Comment: i will try writing macros... its a bit more work. speed is essential. hundreds of files, thousands of lines, not much time... every microsecond adds up. copy&paste was very fast that way. i have commands in separate terminal i can just highlight as needed.

Comment: Ah okay. If the commands already exist elsewhere and are something you want to re-use then what I'd then personally do is convert them into mappings or Vimscript functions that use `:normal`. There's no obvious benefit to recording macros if you already have the commands set up. If you do try using macros in the future, then consider using `:set lazyredraw` to improve their speed.

Answer (score 1):

For key command (i.e. Normal command (like suggested by @Rich) I would do:

```
@*
```

Or

```
@+
```

Provided you have:

```
:set clipboard=unnamed
```

Or

```
:set clipboard=unnamedplus
```

For Vim commands I would do:

- Copy the sequence of commands,
- Create a new buffer (`:enew`),
- Past it into it (`p`), no need to save the buffer and
- Run:

```
:%so
```

Comment: @* seems to work well. but one more keystroke (doubles time it takes) ... everything above fractions of seconds is too slow. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If the sequence of commands is on separate lines and stored on the system clipboard you can try to run

```
call execute(split(@*, "\n"), '')
```

This splits the contents of the clipboard (the star register) into one string per line and passes the resulting list of strings to the `execute()` function.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I paste sequence of Vim (normal mode) commands?

This is very unclear to be frank.

> simple example e.g. commands = JJJj (three joins and a cursor down one line) say, i am in huge text file containing repetitive output, which i want to transform to make it visually more concise. i don't want to punch in those JJJj every time. but just paste the commands... repetitively a few dozen (or hundred) times. maybe even in 10s, e.g. JJJjJJJjJJJjJJJjJJJjJJJjJJJjJJJjJJJjJJJj

You can use ex-command `:join` for it:

```
first line1
first line2
first line3
first line4
second line1
second line2
second line3
second line4
```

`:1,4join` and then `:2,5join` or similar using different `:h range` variations. Or use visual mode with `J` to have:

```
first line1 first line2 first line3 first line4
second line1 second line2 second line3 second line4
```

[image: asciicast]

If it is about "repetitive" thing, you can either use macro recording or a simple `:%normal! JJJ` over your buffer (or selection):

[image: asciicast]

Comment: it was just an example. i'm not confused about the join thing. its just i punch in various commands frequently and need to apply them in fractions of seconds across thousands of lines... visually supervising what's going on. copy&paste is very fast.